# jquery select title and output to do div

Tags: jquery

this my html

```
<section class="section">
   <div class="title">
      <h2>Title 1</h2>
   </div>
</section>
<section class="section">
   <div class="title">
     <h2>title 2</h2>
   </div>
</section>
```

this my selector jquery code

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var text = $('.section').find('.title h2').text(),
    $('.output a').html(text);
});
```

this out put to div

```
<div class="output">
 <a href="">title1title2</a>
</div>
<div class="output">
 <a href="">title1title2</a>
 </div>
```

ı want this is

```
<div class="output">
  <a href="">title1</a>
</div>
<div class="output">
 <a href="">title2</a>
 </div>
```

ı want this just take a section child in h2 and output in to div

Comment: [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) or [`.html(function)`](https://api.jquery.com/html/#html-function)

Answer (score 1):

You can make it like this using $.each .

```
$('.section').find('.title h2').each(function(i, item){
    let text = $(item).text();
    $($('.output a')[i]).html(text);
});
```

This snippet sets i-th 'h2' tag text to i-th 'a' tag html.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('.title').each(function(i){
        var text = $(this).find('h2').text()
        var output = $('.output a');

        output.each(function(){
            $(output[i]).html(text.toLowerCase());
        })
    })

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="section">
   <div class="title">
      <h2>Title 1</h2>
   </div>
</section>
<section class="section">
   <div class="title">
     <h2>title 2</h2>
   </div>
</section>

<div class="output">
 <a href="">title1title2</a>
</div>
<div class="output">
 <a href="">title1title2</a>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the title elements with the `each()` function. You can use the `eq()` function to get the corresponding a element in the output div.

Better would be to have an html structure that that is not depended on the same amount of elements in each selector.

```js
$('.section .title h2').each(function(index) {
  //make sure to have the same amount of a elements in output as h2 elements in title.
  $('.output a').eq(index).html($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="section">
  <div class="title">
    <h2>Title 1</h2>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="section">
  <div class="title">
    <h2>title 2</h2>
  </div>
</section>

<div class="output">
  <a href="">replace this</a>
</div>
<div class="output">
  <a href="">replace this</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help you. There are many ways you can achieve it.

```
<section class="section">
   <div class="title">
    <h2>Title 1</h2>
   </div>
</section>
<section class="section">
   <div class="title">
    <h2>title 2</h2>
   </div>
</section>
<div class='opt'></div>

$( document ).ready(function() {
$('.section').find('.title h2').each(function(){
  var text = $(this).text();
  $('.opt').append('<div class="output"><a href="">'+text+'</a></div>');
 })
});
```